# Magento 2 - Configurable product with multiple price attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, magento2.3, export

I'm facing a dead-end with my **configurable product** and my **simple products**.

Right now, i am struggling setting up my **configuration prices** in a way that make sense for my products.

Since **Magento 2** , the simple product prices 100% overrule the configurable one. That makes perfect sense, but if the price is depending on more than one **attribute**, its getting useless.

Example product: A Chair.

Attribute 1 - Fabric:

- Leather (300$)
- Regular Fabric (100$)

Attribute 2 - Color

- Blue: (50$)
- Black (100$)

Out of the box **Magento** only allow me to base my price on one of the above attributes. 
If i base my price on **"Fabric"** - my two product would then cost:
300$ and 100$ - and my color prices are not taken into account.

So therefore, i am looking for a way to achieve my prices getting based on both of my **attributes**, so my prices instead will be:

- Leather & Blue = 350$
- Leather & Black = 400$
- Regular Fabric & Blue = 150$
- Regular Fabric & Black = 200$

Are there any way? Or suggestions for a work around?

(Only workaround so far that came to my mind, was to **export** every of variant to a **csv-file**, update the price on every variant (sometimes +200), and then import my **new prices** again. But again, this would never work in practice.)

Kindly regards.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this (other than the csv option which as you said is impractical?) I can't believe Magento 2 has this kind of limitation, there HAS to be a way.

Comment: We ended up coding our own module to easier update all the simple's product price. So my simple products are still created with magento's default configuration-wizard, but i will afterwards use our own module to update the prices manually. 

Still not the perfect solution, but much better  than the csv.